# How can I change the original color when te header has class "sticky"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I am working on a website for myself and I have this really cool hover effect where it picks a random color defined in a array and puts it in. When your cursor goes away, it changes back to normal.

And that's where the problems start.

The color changing elements are all located in the header. The header changes its color if the user scrolls down. If the user scrolls down, the header gets the class "sticky" and becomes black.

Here is the website: [m-sch.cf](http://m-sch.cf)

And here is the jquery:

```
var randomLinks = $('.navlink');
var original = randomLinks.css("color");
var colors = ['#ee6161', '#00f2a6', '#01c0fa'];

$(".navlink").hover(
    function () { //mouseover
        var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        var newcolor = colors[col2];
        $(this).css('color', newcolor);
    }, 
    function () { //mouseout
        $(this).css('color', original);
    }
);
```

The default color is set to the class "navlink", which is black. And as we know, black on black is not very good.

Is there any way I an make it so that when the header has the class "sticky", the original color of "navlink" becomes white?

Greetings

Martin

Comment: I have found the 'easy way'. It is just simple fix. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your hover related code is adding inline style color black to a tags, that is the issue here

```
<a href="index.html" class="navlink" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Home</a>
```

`style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);` is getting added to above a tag after hover, if you load the page and scroll below without hovering the menu then they are white, and after hover each menu is getting hardcoded to be black as explained

**UPDATE after comment from OP:**

Use the code below

```
$('a.navlink').css('color', '');
```

instead of

```
$(this).css('color', original);
```

in your event handler (mouse out part) should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following in your CSS:

```
header.sticky .navlink {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Make also sure to remove `style="color:rgb(0,0,0);"` in your HTML, because this part of the codes overwrites the CSS above:

`<a href="index.html" class="navlink">Martin Schmidt</a>`

Comment: I updated the website with your corrections and it sadly doesn't work. Do I have to remove the "header.sticky ul li a { color: white; }"? I also updated my question so you also see the jquery I am using.

Comment: @MartinSchmidt I guess you have to remove this part from your link in your HTML and then it should work: `style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);` This part is hard coded and overwrites your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

On your website I saw that elements with `navlink` are already targeted like this:

```
header.sticky ul li a { color: white; }
```

The above selector has a higher priority than `.navlink`, so currently that's what being applied. Anyway, I think you're looking for this:

```
header.sticky .navlink { color: #ffffff !important; }
```

*Optionally, you can add the `!important` parameter to the color value to increase priority or make the selector more specific.*

Let me know how it does!

**UPDATE:** the `!important` selector is needed here.

**Initial:**

[image: Initial]

**After edit:**

[image: After edit]

Comment: I updated the website with your corrections and it sadly doesn't work. Do I have to remove the "header.sticky ul li a { color: white; }"? I also updated my question so you also see the jquery I am using.

Comment: Hi Martin, I checked it and the problem was that the `header.sticky .navlink` didn't have enough priority (another selector was deemed more important). That was because there is added a color to each `style` tag of each element, which made the  `header.sticky .navlink` not work. If you add `!important` after the color, it does work. `header.sticky .navlink { color: #ffffff !important; }`. (I know that you should restrict the use of !important as much as possible, but in this situation there was no other option. I tried to increase the priority of the selector, but that wasn't enough.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is , instead of changing style attribute of `.navlink` with js (which changes inline css and has higher order than css file rules), change the `data-color` attribute and in css file, assign proper color to it, and then it will be easy to change default color of navlink in css when its sticky.

JS:

```js
    var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
    $('.navlink').on('mouseover', function(e) {
        var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        var newcolor = colors[col2];
        $(this).data('color', newcolor);
    }
```

CSS:

```css
    .navlink[data-color=red]{
        color: red;
    } 
    .navlink[data-color=green]{
        color: green;
    } 
    .navlink[data-color=blue]{
        color: blue;
    } 
    
    .sticky .navlink{
        color:white;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change `$(el).css('color')` to `$(el).style('color')`. So that jQuery will target the CSS selector instead of the inline style.

```
var randomLinks = $('.navlink');
var original = randomLinks.style("color");
var colors = ['#ee6161', '#00f2a6', '#01c0fa'];

$(".navlink").hover(
    function () { //mouseover
        var col2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        var newcolor = colors[col2];
        $(this).style('color', newcolor);
    }, 
    function () { //mouseout
        $(this).style('color', original);
    }
);

var rdmlinks = $('.rdmcolorlink');
var orig = rdmlinks.style('color');
var clr = ['#ee6161', '#00f2a6', '#01c0fa'];

rdmlinks.hover(function () { //mouseover
    var clr2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * clr.length);
    var newclr = clr[clr2];
    $(this).style('color', newclr);
}, function () { //mouseout
    $(this).style('color', orig);
});
```